# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.formula.FormulaContext

Tags: java, maven, pdi

I am invoking a Pentaho Kettle Job using java. 
    The transformations were developed using `PDI CE version 5.4.0.1-130` 
    I have added the below maven dependencies in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-dbdialog</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle5-log4j-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-db</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.4.1</version>
</dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libcss</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libdocbundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfonts</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libformat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
  <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libloader</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libpensol</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libpixie</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>librepository</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libserializer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libsparkline</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libxml</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
          <artifactId>libswing</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
            <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
            <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Repository in pom is referring to `http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo`

When I run the same code in my local, which is Windows 7, it runs fine. When I am running the code in Linux, I am getting the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.formula.FormulaContext
```

I tried changing the version of `pentaho-kettle` to 5.4.0.1-130. But then it threw an exception on `iPentahoSession`.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Bhavya

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded your dependencies, try `mvn install` (or `mvn package`)

Comment: While building the code, I am using `mvn clean install`.

Comment: That error generally means that some class that you are calling is not in your dependencies, why this is I cannot say. The fact that you get a different error using a different version suggests that the class may have been changed or removed in the new version.